# What are other WebsocketClient implementations in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jetty, spring-websocket

I have a Spring application which is connecting to the websocket endpoint. For this I use Spring StandardWebSocketClient class.

```
WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient();
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
String url = "ws://localhost:8080/asynccontrol";
StompSessionHandler handler = new MySessionHandler();
stompClient.connect(url, handler);
```

This works in Jetty without any problem. Now I have to deploy this application in Websphere JRE7 environment. As this WAS version does not support JSR-356, I have to use another implementation. From this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) WebsocketClient can be of type:

- StandardWebSocketClient in a JSR-356 runtime
- JettyWebSocketClient using the Jetty 9+ native WebSocket API
- Any implementation of Spring’s WebSocketClient

First choice unavailable (no JSR-356 runtime), second choice unavailable (needs JRE8, getting unsupported major.minor version 52), what is this third choice? What are other implementations of Spring's WebSocketClient?

May it be possible to recompile org.eclipse.jetty.websocketclient in JRE7?

**Solution**

I cannot use jetty9.2 because it is not compatible with JettyWebSocketClient adapter. However I could just possibly use the api without adapter, with StandardWebSocketClient.

I installed tomcat8 and it works with StandardWebSocketClient too. In tomcat7 I was still getting incompatible WsContainerProvider subtype error, maybe a bug for my specific tomcat version. For the backup plan I have also developed TyrusWebSocketClient. Thank you guys.

Comment: It is possible to use Jetty 9.2.x WebSocket client API in JRE7 (only Jetty 9.3.x is for JRE8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tyrus-standalone client](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/tyrus/bundles/tyrus-standalone-client/1.9/).

If you are using Maven, add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
     <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
     <artifactId>websocket-ri-bundle</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

I have used `websocket-ri-bundle` (second dependency) it works, but any one of these two will work fine.

**EDIT**

If you see `StandardWebsocketClient` class

```
public StandardWebSocketClient() {
    this.webSocketContainer = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
}
```

Spring tries to identify the Container provider from `META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider` file of client implementation. So any websocket client implementation which correctly points out this file will work.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not Spring's implementation. How would I initialize it with tyrus websocket client object?

Comment: It does not need to be spring websocket implementation, spring will automatically identify it. updated my answer.

Comment: @Mejmo I mean it does not need to be `Spring's implementation`, it just needs to be `websocketclient`'s implementation.

Comment: Yeah but spring uses adapter between the implementation and spring (in case of jetty is it JettyWebSocketClient). I decided to make my own TyrusWebSocketClient for Spring. However, thank you for the hint. Im using tyrus everywhere, but it did not came to my mind ..

Comment: It's fine if you want to write your own `TyrusWebSocketClient`, but that is lot of effort. You might not want  to spend time on something which is already done.

Comment: Actually your solution did not work in Tomcat. I was getting  javax.websocket.ContainerProvider: Provider org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsContainerProvider not a subtype . I already implemented TyrusWebSocketClient... is it a bug in tomcat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87000/discussion-between-reservoir-sampling-and-mejmo).

Comment: I have load tested my websocket application using `websocket-ri-bundle` using tomcat 8 and it worked fine. I used code from here -   https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/load/StompWebSocketLoadTestClient.java